# Ms Access VBA: Why is this date comparison not working?

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2016, sql-server-2019

I am trying to compare 2 dates. One of them is stored in my SQL Server database, the other comes from user input on a form. I am entering 6/5/2023 for the end date and 11:54 AM for the end time and then adding them together. This should not trigger the message box, yet it does. Why is this happening?

```
   Dim varStartTimestamp As Variant
   Dim varEndTimestamp As Variant
   
   varStartTimestamp = GetCDV(OpenArgs, 2) '2023-06-05 11:53:25.063 in the database
   varEndTimestamp = [txtDate] + [txtTime] 'User inputs
   
   If varEndTimestamp <= varStartTimestamp Then
      MsgBox "The date and time you entered must be after the original date and time"
      Exit Sub
   End If
```

Comment: @HansUp it shows this: `June 5 2023`

Comment: OK.  No idea what `GetCDV()` does.  What do you see for `TypeName(varStartTimestamp)` and `Format(varStartTimestamp, "yyyy-m-d hh:nn:ss")` ?

Comment: @HansUp it just gets the database datetime value. I put the value it's getting on the right. Those things print out `String` and `2023-6-5 11:53:25`

Comment: Handling dates as strings can be trouble.  Not sure that's the problem here, but I would check by transforming the string to date type for the comparison.  Something like `CDate(Left(varStartTimestamp, 19))`  If VBA also sees `varEndTimestamp` as a string, apply `CDate()` to it as well.

Answer (score 0):

Always handle date and time as DateTime.

If `OpenArgs` holds the string `2023-06-05 11:53:25.063`, convert it to *Date*:

```vb
    Dim StartTimestamp  As Date
    Dim EndTimestamp    As Date
   
    StartTimestamp = CDate(Left(OpenArgs, 19)) 
    EndTimestamp = DateValue([txtDate]) + TimeValue([txtTime]) 
   
    If DateDiff("s", EndTimestamp, StartTimestamp) >= 0 Then
        MsgBox "The date and time you entered must be after the original date and time"
        Exit Sub
    End If
```